# How to delete all documents in Cloud Firestore except one?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Cloud Firestore in my Flutter app. I want to delete all documents under TestApp/Dashboard, except the one with `ID` that matches today's date. Let say today's date is 12th December 2020. I know that it's possible to delete all documents but I haven't found any regarding delete all with exceptions.

My Cloud Firestore database

```
- TestApp
  - Dashboard
    - 2020/12/12
      - totalDailyVisitors: 12
    - 2020/12/11
      - totalDailyVisitors: 34
    - 2020/12/10
      - totalDailyVisitors: 56
```

How do I perform deletion for all documents with `ID` other than 2020/12/12?

Comment: Firestore does not have bulk delete capabilities.  You will have to query for the documents you want to delete, iterate the query results, then delete each document individually.  If you are trying to delete everything but one, you could simply read the entire collection, and skip deleting the one document that should remain.

Comment: I see. This is very similar to [Shri Hari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65025164/7576217)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, I would like to give you an idea.

I think it is not possible to delete with exceptions. But we can make use of batch operations.

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/64), make it for Flutter like this,

```
WriteBatch _batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

QuerySnapshot _query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Dashboard').getDocuments();

_query.documents.forEach((doc) {
     if(doc.documentID != 'YOUR DATE'){
         _batch.delete(doc.ref);
     }
});

await _batch.commit();
```

As mentioned in the issue, it also has some limits!

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Comment: This is the most helpful answer to my question. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the needed document first and then exclude it from deletion of the document. For example:

```
refUser.where("date", != "2020/12/12").getDocuments().then((snapshot){
    snapshot.documents.first.reference.delete();
});
```

Make a **back-up** of your files first since I do not know for sure if this works!!! ***Edit:*** Change date to what it needs to be. (Didn't know for sure if it needed to be ***ID*** so I changed it with a *date* placeholder)

Comment: It doesn't work since where() expects parameter of type field and I need to delete all except one based on documentID